# Did I damage my appliance by shorting the power wires in the junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, garbage-disposal

Dish disposal was jammed and I unjammed it with the allen wrench but didn't take out the allen wrench and when I turned it on it wrapped the wiring around the allen wrench and pulled the wiring nuts off.

Well the white neutral wire of the dish disposal was hidden inside the cover of the bottom of the disposal and I didn't see it. I thought it was odd that there was only 1 black wire hanging out the bottom of the disposal, but I continued to wire the hot and neutral of the extension cord to the 1 black wire out the disposal and saw a spark and of course it didn't turn on.

I realized that there are 2 wires coming out of the disposal and then proceeded to wire it correctly.  The disposal does not work and does not see to have power.  Did I short of burn out the dish disposal and need to replace it??

Comment: Did you push the little reset button on the bottom of the  disposal?

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't hurt the garbage disposal, but you probably tripped the circuit breaker in your electrical panel. You may have also fried the switch for the disposal, or any outlets, cords or wires between the disposal and the breaker.

Comment: One would hope OP would have turned off the breaker to work on the wiring, which would have had the effect of resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a ltl red button sometimes black on the bottom push it in to reset overload..sounds like a badger type disposal

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.